# differential equation and its integration

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, legendre-polynomials

I am solving a problem that in which I got a differential equation of the form
$$\sum_{l=0}^{l=\infty}\left[\frac{d^2g_{l}}{dz^2}-\frac{l(l+1)g_{l}}{z(z-1)}\right]p_{l}(cos\theta)=-\frac{2q}{z} \delta(z-a) \delta(cos\theta - 1)$$
Now integration is performed such that from $-a$ to $a$ and the result obtained is 
$$\left[\frac{dg_{l}}{dz}\right]_{z=-a}^{z=+a}=-\frac{(2l+1)q}{a}$$
I don't know how?
I shall be very thank full if if any one will help!

Comment: If you integrate a series, in many cases where the functions are decently well behaved (read: if the series converges uniformly), the summation and the integration commute.

Comment: @themathandlanguagetutor sir it is differential equation whose solution appear in term of Legendre polynomials